# Evitar enviar formulario si tengo radiobuttons seleccionados

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, web

estoy haciendo un embed code para un formulario de mailchimp
tengo 4 opciones
OP 1,2,3 y 4

Cada una tiene 2 radiobuttons SI y NO
como hago para que el formulario no se envie si TODOS LOS RADIOBUTTONS ESTAN EN NO

```
  <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="mce-MMERGE4-0" checked> <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label>
 <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="mce-MMERGE4-1"> 
                        <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Y también, ¿que no se envíe si TODOS los radiobuttons están en no?¿o que no se envíe si alguno de ellos está en no?

Comment: Hay más código que ese? Podrías poner tu código completo para analizarlo mejor. Puedes usar javascript para esa validación o usa required, pero como te digo, con algo más de código podría ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto! espero te sirva

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="" id="id_form">
        <div>
            <label>UNO</label><br>
            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="1-mce-MMERGE4-0"/> 
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label>
            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="1-mce-MMERGE4-1"/> 
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>DOS</label><br>
            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="2-mce-MMERGE4-0"> 
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label>
            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="2-mce-MMERGE4-1"/>
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>TRES</label><br>
            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="3-mce-MMERGE4-0"> 
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label>
            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="3-mce-MMERGE4-1"/> 
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>CUATRO</label><br>
            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="4-mce-MMERGE4-0"> 
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label>
            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="4-mce-MMERGE4-1"/>
            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Ejecutar" name="btn" id="btn"> 
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#id_form").on('submit', function (evt) {

            if (!$("#1-mce-MMERGE4-0").is(':checked') && 
!$("#2-mce-MMERGE4-0").is(':checked') && !$("#3-mce-MMERGE4-0").is(':checked') && !$("#4-mce-MMERGE4-0").is(':checked')) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                alert('No has marcado un Sí');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

con jquery podrias hacer esto

```
function validar(){
 var valida = true
 $("#contenedor-radius").find("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
 if($(this).val()=='no'){
  valida=false
 }
})
 return valida

}
```

antes de enviar el formulario has este condicional

```
if(validar()){
  enviar...
} else {
 No enviar ...
}
```